# Install 64bits os on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu, 64-bit, freebsd

I'm not able to run 64-bit OS on my Raspberry Pi 4.
If I do these steps (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md) with a 32bit OS it works fine, but if I use Ubuntu or FreeBSD then it doesn't boot. The screen keeps blank. Is there any special step when it is a 64 bit OS?

Comment: Perhaps have a look at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=249248

Comment: Note: FreeBSD states that there is NO (current) support for Raspberry pi 4 - does Ubuntu support it yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [FreeBSD/ARM on the Raspberry Pi family](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi)

> For Raspberry Pi 4 (NOT supported yet) use the image for RPI3

You might want to try the latest [FreeBSD-13.0-CURRENT-arm64-aarch64-RPI3](https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/snapshots/ISO-IMAGES/13.0/FreeBSD-13.0-CURRENT-arm64-aarch64-RPI3-20190815-r351067.img.xz) (410MB).

No RPI4 has been [reported installed](http://dmesgd.nycbug.org/index.cgi?do=index&fts=raspberry+pi+) yet.

---

FWIW, as of Linux  see [Support of Raspberry Pi](https://forum.armbian.com/topic/483-support-of-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: Is there a 64 bit OS available for rp 4?

Comment: There is no RPI4 dedicated image in [CURRENT](https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/snapshots/ISO-IMAGES/13.0/) yet. Meanwhile, Wiki suggests using RPI3 images.

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad there area a few listed here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100926/64bit-os-on-raspberry-pi-4/101802

Your title, question, and followup aren't consistent. Are you asking about any 64-bit OS for the Pi 4 or specifically FreeBSD and Ubuntu? Please edit your question to clarify.